# Regex to match greek characters?

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I constructed the following regex

```
preg_match_all('#(autom(.*?)tic|(.*?)anual)#', $str2b, $gears);
```

but I want to change it to match greek characters. I would like to match the words `βενζίνη` and  `πετρέλαιο` but I don't get it to work.

```
preg_match_all('#(βενζί(.*?)η|πετρέλ(.*?)ιο)#', $str2b, $gears);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I would avoid embedding unicode in regular expressions unless the engine doesn't support \u or \x{}, and does unicode. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `/u` regex switch for unicode matching:

```
preg_match_all('#(βενζί(.?)η|πετρέλ(.?)ιο)#u', $str2b, $gears);
```

btw you can use `\p{Greek}` property for matching Greek letters.