# Accept only greek letters in autosave input

Tags: javascript, regex

I want my textbox to accept only Greek letters. I use this code but doesn't work.

JS:

```
<script language="javascript">
     document.logOn.onsubmit = validate;
     function validate() { 
         var name = document.logOn.pw.value;
         if(!name = " [A-ZA-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]") {
             alert("Δεν επιτρεπονται λατινικη χαρακτηρες!");
             return false;
         }
         return true;
     }
<script>
```

In HTML I use, `onkeypress = validate()`

Comment: so your code works??

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Can you give us inputs that don't work and some that work. And the expected result.

Comment: I randomly press english letters and accept them.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `string.match(regexp)` for regex matching. Also, I believe that the regex should be `/^[A-ZA-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]+$/`

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255329/php-and-regexp-to-accept-only-greek-characters-in-form) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19188893/regex-to-match-greek-characters).

I'm not an expert on the Greek alphabet, but something like this seems to work:

```
(/^[Α-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]+$/).test('ιτρε'); // true
(/^[Α-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]+$/).test('ιτρεkalimera'); // false
```

So, in your condition:

```
if ( (/^[Α-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]+$/).test(name) ) {
   // you are speaking Greek to me
}
```

Comment: I think that " " required

Comment: I don't understand. You need to check for quotes in the string as well?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not use regex. `!name = " [A-ZA-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]"` mean `name` literally must be `[A-ZA-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]`.

Convert it to regex `if (!name.test(/ [A-ZA-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]+/))`. [`.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) returns true/false

---

Your regex would match `{space}{any letter fro A to Z or from A to z or form A to Ω or α to ω or any of ίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ}`

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function validate()
{
    var name=document.getElementById('logOn').pw.value;
    if(!(new RegExp("[Α-Ωα-ωίϊΐόάέύϋΰήώ]").test(name)))
    {
        alert("Δεν επιτρεπονται λατινικη χαρακτηρες!");
        return false;
    }


    return true;

}
    window.onload = function() {   document.getElementById('logOn').onsubmit = validate; };

</script>
```

This will alert if the text contains letters other than that in RegEx.

Comment: Please Note: Op didn't ask for characters A-Z a-z in the text.

Comment: Still not working. As I mention in HTML I put the function in onkeypress

Comment: My bad wrote the answer in hurry.
That was because of the statement document.logOn .Try It Now.

Comment: Thanks for help but doesnt work. . In my case I have a plain text that when I click enter appear an alert that mention my inncorrect inputs

Comment: What do you mean you have plain text Please improve you question

Comment: I have an input text and there is no button to save the value. When I press enter the value saved in database

Comment: I have an input text i want to say. Also when replace logOn with my input id and when i remove pw seems to work but when appear the alert continue to accept the incorrect inputs and also when i press any key in keyboard appears the alert

Comment: Give me an input which is not working for you, in the above code.
I tried pressing enter the alert system works.
For Me: 
I entered : Abc - popup 
I entered : Ω - no popup 
and also some other cases

What input is not working for you man.
Also what do u mean you press any key keyboard alert occurs ?
Do You want that to happen or not.?
appear the alert continue to accept the incorrect inputs ???

Dude please improve your grammar I am really unable to understand

If you have your webpage hosted somewhere please provide a link.
(* i dont know if its allowed in SO though *)

Comment: I dont want english letter. For example when i insert the letter e.g a the alert appears but the letter appear in the input text also

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem is here

```
    document.logOn.onsubmit = validate;
     var name = document.logOn.pw.value;
```

Maybe I need to use something else. I suppose this works on submit input. In my case I have a plain text that when I click enter appear an alert that mention my inncorrect inputs. Any usefull advice is accepted

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that have been existed yet is that the alert  is appeared but are accepted  incorrect entries.
I suppose that my jacascript is correct and the problem  appear in my HTML code. I use onclick='return validate ()'